# What special considerations need to be made for a US citizen who wishes to purchase a house in Canada?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, real-estate, property-taxes

According to an [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/49493/969) on a previous question, buying a house in Canada if you are a US citizen is pretty straightforward.

But it doesn't address tax concerns in both countries - how are they handled?

Can mortgage interest or property tax paid in Canada be deducted from your US income taxes?

Does property ownership make you liable for other taxes in Canada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About **deducting mortgage interest**: No, you can not deduct it unless it is qualified mortgage interest. "Qualified mortgage interest is interest and points you pay on a loan secured by your main home or a second home." (Tax Topic 505).  According to the IRS, "if you rent out the residence, you must use it for more than 14 days or more than 10% of the number of days you rent it out, whichever is longer."

Regarding **being taxed on income received** from the property, if you claim the foreign tax credit you will not be double taxed. According to the IRS, "The foreign tax credit intends to reduce the double tax burden that would otherwise arise when foreign source income is taxed by both the United States and the foreign country from which the income is derived."  (from IRS Topic 856 - Foreign Tax Credit)

About **property taxes**: From my understanding, these cannot be claimed for the foreign tax credit but can be deducted as business expenses.

There are various **exceptions and stipulations** based on your circumstance, so you need to read the official publications and get professional tax advice. Here's an excerpt from Publication 856 - Foreign Tax Credit for Individuals:
"In most  cases,  only  foreign  income  taxes  qualify for the foreign tax credit. Other taxes, such as foreign real and personal property taxes, do not qualify.  But  you  may  be  able  to  deduct  these other  taxes  even  if  you  claim  the  foreign  tax credit for foreign income taxes. In most cases, you can deduct these other taxes  only  if  they  are  expenses incurred  in  a trade  or  business  or  in  the  production  of  in­come.  However,  you  can  deduct  foreign  real property taxes that are not trade or business ex­penses  as  an  itemized  deduction  on  Sched­ule A (Form 1040)."

Note and disclaimer:

- This question refers to an answer that has since been updated. I included most of that update here.
- Be sure to get professional advice from an accountant and a real estate agent. I am neither.

Sources:
[IRS Tax Topic 505 Interest Expense](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc505.html),
[IRS Real Estate (Taxes, Mortgage Interest, Points, Other Property Expenses)](https://www.irs.gov/help-resources/tools-faqs/faqs-for-individuals/frequently-asked-tax-questions-answers/itemized-deductions-standard-deduction/real-estate-taxes-mortgage-interest-points-other-property-expenses/real-estate-taxes-mortgage-interest-points-other-property-expenses-5) ,
[IRS Topic 514 Foreign Tax Credit](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p514.pdf) , and
[Publication 856 Foreign Tax Credit for Individuals](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc856.html)